# I keep loosing the first key/value pair when adding the values

Tags: javascript

So I want to run two objects through this function, have it compare the keys and then add the values of the keys that match.  For some reason, it's just chopping off the first key/value pair and I'm not sure why.  My guess is something to do with the nested for loops but I can't seem to wrap my head around where the malfunction is.

```
const necro = { 
  health: 6,
  attack: 2,
  armor: 4,
  focus: 0,
  speed: 0,
  recover: 10,
}
const baseCharacter = { 
    health: 8,
    attack: 8,
    armor: 8,
    focus: 8,
    speed: 8,
    recover: 8,
  }
const statCompare = (myObj,staticObj) => {
  let myVal = Object.values(myObj)
  let baseVal = Object.values(staticObj)
  let newVal = []
  for(let i = 0; i < myVal.length;i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < baseVal.length;j++){
      if (i=j){
        statSum =  myVal[i] + baseVal[j]
        newVal.push(statSum)
      }
    }
  }
  return newVal
}

npcStats = statCompare(necro, baseCharacter)
console.log(npcStats)
```

console.log returns [10,12,8,8,18]

Comment: "if ( i = j )" should be "if ( i=== j )" and you need to declare variables "let statSum, let npcStats" before use it.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've been troubleshooting since I posted this and I literally just realized I needed the === and came here to update the post!  Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const necro = { 
  health: 6,
  attack: 2,
  armor: 4,
  focus: 0,
  speed: 0,
  recover: 10,
}

const baseCharacter = { 
    health: 8,
    attack: 8,
    armor: 8,
    focus: 8,
    speed: 8,
    recover: 8,
  }

const statCompare = (myObj, staticObj) => {
  const result = [];
  
  for (let [k1, v1] of Object.entries(myObj)) {
    for (let [k2, v2] of Object.entries(staticObj)) {
      if (k1 === k2) result.push(v1 + v2);
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(statCompare(necro, baseCharacter));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on index of object values to compare different objects. It is error prone approach.
Instead, rely on object keys.

Actually I have multiple notes on your code:

1. Operate with object keys instead of relying on indices.
2. "for" loop inside other "for" loop is redundant. Only one iteration is needed.
3. Return result as object instead of array of numbers (again, indices are easy to mismatch and introduce more bugs to the app).
4. Function name is confusing. I don't see how you compare stats actually. You only sum values of the same keys - it is different. Rename it to e.g. `mergeObjectValues`.
5. Property "armor" is a typo. Expected word is "armour".
6. Handle possibly undefined values with default "0" value. So you will not receive `NaN`.

Therefore, a better code is like next:

```js
const necro = { 
  health: 6,
  attack: 2,
  armour: 4,
  focus: 0,
  speed: 0,
  recover: 10,
}

const baseCharacter = { 
  health: 8,
  attack: 8,
  armour: 8,
  focus: 8,
  speed: 8,
  recover: 8,
}

const mergeObjectValues = (myObj, staticObj) => {
  const result = {};
  
  // keys should be from object with full list of possible keys
  const keys = Object.keys(myObj);
  keys.forEach(k => {
    const v1 = myObj[k] || 0;
    const v2 = staticObj[k] || 0;
    result[k] = v1 + v2;
  });
  
  return result;
}

console.log(mergeObjectValues(necro, baseCharacter));
```

Result is clear and easy to work with further:

```js
{
  "health": 14,
  "attack": 10,
  "armour": 12,
  "focus": 8,
  "speed": 8,
  "recover": 18
}
```

If you really need just an array of numbers and order is not important, this is the place where you use `Object.values`

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice and criticism!  I'm still fumbling around with learning the basics of Javascript so I really appreciate your insight!